ASP.Net - query Informix Database without client installation
Looking to connect to an IBM Informix database from a ASP.Net application. Is this possible with nugets/references without any SKU or client package installation?
I see that this is possible with JDBC driver through dbeaver for example, is there such drivers compatible with the .net framework? ADO.NET?
I need to deploy this app on multiple corporate servers through their house tools, and I have no easy way to install client packages on them.
So far I tried the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries nuget (read to use db2 as Informix deprecated) and IBM.Data.Informix nuget. Both need prior installation (exceptions at connection with missing dll like cwbdc.dll or iclit09b.dll)
I appreciate any help pointing to this elusive package, if even possible.
Thanks!
EDIT:
Well after some more reading it became obvious that this approach was not possible, so if anyone is looking for a similar solution, I decided to use JDBC.NET.Data which is a JDBC driver Wrapper that can be used without any client installation.
